# How to create a rectangle outline in vuejs without having to install any packages?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to create a rectangle outline using vueJS without any luck.
I am hoping this can done with only CSS, but i try many way to do it without any solution.
I am trying to do something like this:
https://codepen.io/sfdevgirl/pen/fdgkJ

[image: two rectangle squares]

```
    <template>
<div v-bind:style="styleObject"></div>
 <div class="shape"
       v-for="shape in shapes"
       v-bind:key=" shape.shape">

       </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {   
shapes: [
      { shape: 'square', animate: true }
    ],
</script>
<Style>
 .syleObject {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.square {
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: it is not my code pen, something i found.. but don't know how to put it in my application.. Bootstrapvue

Comment: this is how mine is coming along: 
https://imgur.com/a/qlDBchE

Comment: after opening the link, I saw its table that they made, so try table inside your shape @Samantha

Comment: Do you want to implement the codepen with `bootstrap-vue` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.square {
  position:relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.square::after {
  position:absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

5px is the gap between the borders.